# 2 graphs mouse motion matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 graphs and a mouse motion function that prints out the coordinates of the canvas they are on. How can I make it so that the mouse motion function is only called when,the mouse hovers over one of the graphs.

```
self.ax.imshow(matrix,cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r, interpolation='none')
self.ax.imshow(matrix2,cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r, interpolation='none')

def motion_capture(event)
    print event.xdata
    print event.ydata


self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self,-1,self.fig)
self.canvas.mpl.connect('Motion', motion_capture)
```

At the moment this is called when the mouse is moving along the canvas, if it is not on either graphs `none` is printed for the coordinates. How can I make it so it only is called for one of the graphs

Comment: you can connect and disconnect your motion capture function based on which axes your mouse has entered/left (which are, themselves, connect-able events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear from your example, but I'm assuming you have separate axes/subplots.  (If that's not the case, then you'll need to do a bit more.)

In that case, it's easiest to just detect which axes the event is in using `event.inaxes`.

As a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

axes[0].imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), interpolation='none')
axes[1].imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), interpolation='none')

def motion_capture(event):
    if event.inaxes is axes[0]:
        print event.xdata
        print event.ydata


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', motion_capture)

plt.show()
```